# Python: slow read & write for millions of small files

Tags: python, file, io

> **Conclusion:**
>   It seems that HDF5 is the way to go for my purposes. Basically "*HDF5 is a data model, library, and file format for storing and managing data.*" and is designed to handle incredible amounts of data. It has a Python module called python-tables. (The link is in the answer below)
>
> *HDF5 does the job done 1000% better in saving tons and tons of data. Reading/modifying the data from 200 million rows is a pain though, so that's the next problem to tackle.*

---

I am building directory tree which has tons of subdirectories and files. There are about 10 million files spread around a hundred thousand directories. Each file is under 32 subdirectories.

I have a python script that builds this filesystem and reads & writes those files. The problem is that when I reach more than a million files, the read and write methods become extremely slow.

Here's the function I have that reads the contents of a file (the file contains an integer string), adds a certain number to it, then writes it back to the original file.

```
def addInFile(path, scoreToAdd):
    num = scoreToAdd
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(path, '/tmp/tmp.txt')
        fp = open('/tmp/tmp.txt', 'r')
        num += int(fp.readlines()[0])
        fp.close()
    except:
        pass
    fp = open('/tmp/tmp.txt', 'w')
    fp.write(str(num))
    fp.close()
    shutil.copyfile('/tmp/tmp.txt', path)
```

- Relational databases seem too slow for accessing these data, so I opted for a filesystem approach.
- I previously tried performing linux console commands for these but it was way slower.
- I copy the file to a temporary file first then access/modify it then copy it back because i found this was faster than directly accessing the file.
- Putting all the files into 1 directory (in reiserfs format) caused too much slowdown when accessing the files.

I think the cause of the slowdown is because there're tons of files. Performing this function 1000 times clocked at less than a second.. but now it's reaching 1 minute.

How do you suggest I fix this? Do I change my directory tree structure?

**All I need is to quickly access each file in this very huge pool of files***

Comment: 256^32!!! That's 1E77!!! It would take you 4E68 1TB disk drives just for the directories!!! If you meant "2^32", then you're in luck, you ONLY need about 4 PETAbytes of storage for that.

Comment: Please go over your numbers, there is no way you can have 256^32 directories on your disk or even 2^32 with current disks and still be asking for help on this. In other words, you wouldn't buy that many or this large disks without knowing how to deal with them properly, so the numbers are obviously wrong.

Comment: Also, you're saying that each file is just a few bytes long but complains that it takes time to process when the file is 1GB?

Comment: I know this value is large. It is 256^32. What I'm doing is writing all the files, then these would be studied and purged accordingly (the time this would take would be a problem for another day). Realistically, only 1% or less of 256^32 would be the kept data.

Comment: What I meant by 1gb size is that when all the files put together reach around 1gb, the read/write operations slow down

Comment: from the description, i understand that the OP is making 256 directories, each containing 256 directories, ..., 32 levels deep. the last level contains 256 small files.

Comment: It seems that there is a confusion with the topic. I'm rephrasing the post.

Comment: I guess there's still some confusion.

Assuming Adrien's explanation of of having a 32-deep 256-tree, you'll have "slighly" above 10^77 directories in total, or just "slightly" above 2^256.

Unfortunately, there are no 256-bit filesystems, so you'll have to wait until those become en vogue (hint: they won't).

Once you have such a 256-bit filesystem, you'll only have to overcome the minor obstacle to [boil the oceans](http://blogs.sun.com/bonwick/entry/128_bit_storage_are_you), twice, and then you're all set with your directory structure.

Comment: Have you ever consider the change of the programming language ?

Comment: Why would you store 1GB of data in millions of files?

Comment: for now i estimate that after all files have been written, the total filesize may reach only 22GB.

Yes i can change programming languages, the question is to what language.

Comment: C? It'd be fast enough. I just can't help thinking that there's a better way to do this. What exactly are you trying to accomplish (at a higher level)?

Comment: that certainly is no question of programming languages, it's one of data organisation and filesystems. i'm absolutely confident that switching to e.g. C while sticking to the same approach the current Python code is using will make no significant difference (read: the code is IO-bound, and C can't do nothing about that).

Comment: At a higher level.. I'm trying to get (e.g.) all the 32-bit 'strings' that exist in the file. technically, in a file, I'm getting bits 0-32, 1-33, 2-34, ...

Comment: `Relational databases seem too slow for accessing these data, so I opted for a filesystem approach.` i still have to see how your approach can be faster than `INSERT INTO board(key,score) SELECT key, SUM(score)+add FROM board WHERE key=?` using a properly configured database... do you really need to store all intermediate scores ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do need them. The bad thing here is, the key is composed of 32 integers (0-255), searching a database can be troublesome

Comment: there is a parallel version of HDF5 that you can access from the C API, not sure if your update process can exploit parallelism but that is something to research as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but it is a direct solution to your problem.

You need to research using something like [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). It is designed for just the type of hierarchical data with millions of individual data points.

You are REALLY in luck because there are awesome Python bindings for HDF5 called [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/).
I have used it in a very similar way and had tremendous success.

Comment: This looks promising! I will test this also. Best thing about this is it's used for scientific data and it uses POSIX format.

Comment: accessing will be really fast if you know the offsets into the "tables" or using the pytables indexes. updating is just going to be how much RAM you have and how fast your disks are, just like anything else. If you have lots of storage, instead of doing in-place updates you might consider copying into a new "table", and be sure and turn compression on as well.

Comment: I have read the manual on HDF5. Indeed, if you know the offset of the rows, or if you're sampling just part of it, it'll be fast but I wanted to search all the data. I would have to rethink the inputting of the data so that I won't have to do row updates anymore. But definitely, HDF5 would my millions of small files

Answer (score 6):

Two suggestions:

**First**, a structure that involves 32-deep nesting of subdirectories is inherently flawed. Assuming that you really have "about 10 million files", one level of subdirectories should absolutely be enough (assuming you use a modern filesystem).

**Second**: You say you have "about 10 million files" and that each file "contains an integer string". Assuming that those are 32-bit integers and you store them directly instead of as strings, that amounts to a total dataset size of 40MiB (10M files * 4 bytes per file). Assuming that each filename is 32 bytes long, add another 320MiB for "keys" to this data.

So you'll be able to *easily fit the whole dataset into memory*. I suggest doing just that, and operate over the data held in main memory. And unless there is any reason you need an elaborate directory structure, I further suggest storing the data in a single file.

Comment: Depending on the filesystem used, one level of subdirectories might be asking for trouble. Not all filesystems perform well with thousands of files in a directory.

Comment: @Mattias: Yes, but that's why you'd ask on serverfault about which is the best FS to deploy this sort of thing.

Comment: True, and now everyone knows both that it might be a problem and where to ask for help. :)

Comment: Mattias, thanks. My discussion rests on the assumption that one uses a modern FS if one wants to store data FS-based. I added a remark to that effect.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you rethink your approach, using lots of extremely small files is bound to give you serious performance problems. Depending on the purpose of your program some kind of database could be far more efficient.

If you're doing lots of I/O you can also just throw more hardware at the problem and use SSDs or keep all the data in RAM (explicitly or by caching). With harddrives alone you have no chance of achiving good performance in this scenario.

I've never used it, but e.g. [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) is a persistent key-value store that is supposed to be very fast. If your data fits this model I would definately try this or something similar. You'll find some performance data in this [article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/08/27/looking-at-redis/), which should give you an idea what speeds you can achieve.

Comment: So what you're saying is since i'm reading/writing billions of small files, harddrives are a big no? I cannot use SSDs or RAM because the estimated amount of data i'm generating just for now is around 22Gb.

Comment: 22 gigabytes easily fit on affordable SSDs, you can get 64GB for less than 200 EUR. I would still suggest you investigate other approaches that cause less I/O.

Comment: any suggestions on the less IO using conventional HDDs?

Comment: Like what? Get 100 of them to still have less IO than a SSD? Bad news - that is how large data warehosues do it. Hunred or more 15k RPM SAS drives, just to get the IO speed. A disc is good for x hundred IOPS - 300 or so with a decent disc. YOu need more IO - get more spindles ;) Or a SSD (RealSSD = 40.000 IOPS).

Comment: Suggestion to reduce amount of IOs: consolidate files!

Comment: I still recommend to use something like a database, because there the I/O optimization has already been perfomed in some way by the database developers. It doesn't have to be a relational database, maybe one of the simpler key-value storage systems fits your need.

Answer (score 2):

1. The disk is limited by amount of bytes it can read/write per second and also by amount of **operations** it can perform in second.
2. While your small files are cached, operations are significantly faster than with uncached files.

It looks like you are hitting both issues,

- doing too many i/o operations
- running out of cache

I'd suggest revisiting the structure you are using, and using less larger files. Keep in minf (as a rule of thumb) than I/O operation less than 128K runtime cost is more or less equal to I/O of 1byte!

Comment: For your #1, I only perform the read/writes sequentially, I do not thread it to perform multiple times. would that still be a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem, but, if the disk is limited to 100 IO operations per second, you'll not be able to read/write more than let's say 70 files (because 1 write cost is (rule of thumb) equal to cost of 4 reads)

Answer (score 2):

Resolving all of those subdirectories takes time. You're over-taxing the file-system.

Maybe instead of using the directory tree, you could instead encode the path information into the file name, so instead of creating a file with a path like this:

```
/parent/00/01/02/03/04/05/06/07
       /08/09/0A/0B/0C/0D/0E/0F
       /10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17
       /18/19/1A/1B/1C/1D/1E/1F.txt
```

...you could create a file with a path like this:

```
/parent/00_01_02_03_04_05_06_07_
        08_09_0A_0B_0C_0D_0E_0F_
        10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_
        18_19_1A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1F.txt
```

...of course, you'll still have a problem, because now all of your ten million files will be in a single directory, and in my experience (NTFS), a directory with more than a few thousand files in it still over-taxes the file-system.

You could come up with a hybrid approach:

```
/parent/00_01_02_03/04_05_06_07
       /08_09_0A_0B/0C_0D_0E_0F
       /10_11_12_13/14_15_16_17
       /18_19_1A_1B/1C_1D_1E_1F.txt
```

But that will still give you problems if you exhaustively create all those directories. Even though most of those directories are "empty" (in that they don't contain any ***files***), the operating system still has to create an INODE record for each directory, and that takes space on disk.

Instead, you should only create a directory when you have a file to put into it. Also, if you delete all the files in any given directory, then delete the empty directory.

How many levels deep should you create the directory hierarchy? In my little example, I transformed your 32-level hierarchy into an 8-level hierarchy, but after doing some testing, you might decide on a slightly different mapping. It really depends on your data, and how evenly those paths are distributed through the combinatorial solution space. You need to optimize a solution with two constraints:

1) Minimize the number of directories you create, knowing that each directory becomes an INODE in the underlying file-system, and creating too many of them will overwhelm the file system.

2) Minimize the number of files in each directory, knowing that having too many files per directory (in my experience, more than 1000) overwhelms the file-system.

There's one other consideration to keep in mind: Storage space on disks is addressed and allocated using "blocks". If you create a file smaller than the minimum block size, it nevertheless consumes the whole block, wasting disk space. In NTFS, those blocks are defined by their "cluster size" (which is partially determined by the overall size of the volume), and usually defaults to 4kB:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365

So if you create a file with only one byte of data, it will still consume 4kB worth of disk space, wasting 4095 bytes.

In your example, you said you had about 10 million files, with about 1gB of data. If that's true, then each of your files is only about 100 bytes long. With a cluster size of 4096, you have about a 98% space-wasted ratio.

If at all possible, try to consolidate some of those files. I don't know what kind of data they contain, but if it's a text format, you might try doing something like this:

```
[id:01_23_45_67_89_AB_CD_EF]
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit
[id:fe_dc_ba_98_76_54_32_10]
ut non lorem quis quam malesuada lacinia
[id:02_46_81_35_79_AC_DF_BE]
nulla semper nunc id ligula eleifend pulvinar
```

...and so on and so forth. It might look like you're wasting space with all those verbose headers, but as far as the disk is concerned, this is a much more space-efficient strategy than having separate files for all those little snippets. This little example used exactly 230 bytes (including newlines) for three records, so you might try to put about sixteen records into each file (remembering that it's much better to have slightly less than 4096 bytes-per-file than to have slightly more than 4096, wasting a whole extra disk block).

Anyhow, good luck!

Comment: Good points.

Indeed I have a lot of wasted space. If i have 1 integer (a value of 0-255) in each file, i can put in 256 of these integers in 1 file to utilize the 4096 block size of the reiserfs filesystem.

I did a test to check which is faster: lots of small files vs 1 file with lots of content. For test 1, I had 65k files with 1 integer each then accessed & modified them 50k times. For test 2, I had 65k lines with 1 integer each in 1 file then accessed & modified them 50k times.

results:
lots of small files: 7.4 secs
lots of content: 5.6 secs

Comment: I checked my test code, seems that the 2 sec delay with the lots of small files test resulted from the opening and closing of a different file. Some sort of caching occurs when the same file is being open/closed all the time.

Comment: If your integer values are in the range of 0 to 255, that can be store in a single byte and you can therefore put 4096 (!) of those in a single file if you want to accomodate a 4KB block size.

Comment: Yes they fill the block size nicely. Please read my 2nd comment on Lie Ryan's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You're copying a file, opening it to read, closing it, then reopening it for writing, then recopying it back. It would be faster to do it in one go.

**EDIT: the previous version has a bug when the number of digits become less than the current number of digits (e.g. if you're subtracting or adding by negative number); this version fixes it, timing result is barely unaffected**

```
def addInFile(path, scoreToAdd):
    try:
        fp = open(path, 'r+')
    except IOError as e:
        print e
    else:
        num = str(scoreToAdd + int(fp.read()))
        fp.seek(0)
        fp.write(num)
        fp.truncate(len(num))
    finally:
        fp.close()
```

alternatively, if you want to avoid file loss and writes to cache, you should do the copying and the summing in one go, then do a an overwrite-dance in another step:

```
def addInFile(path, scoreToAdd):
    try:
        orig = open(path, 'r')
        tmp = open('/home/lieryan/junks/tmp.txt', 'w')
    except IOError as e:
        print e
    else:
        num = int(orig.read())
        tmp.write(str(scoreToAdd + num))
    finally:
        orig.close()
        tmp.close()
    try:
        # make sure /tmp/ and path is in the same partition
        # otherwise the fast shutil.move become a slow shutil.copy
        shutil.move(path, '/home/lieryan/junks/backup.txt')
        shutil.move('/home/lieryan/junks/tmp.txt', path)
        os.remove('/home/lieryan/junks/backup.txt')
    except (IOError, shutil.Error) as e:
        print e
```

also, don't use bare excepts.

Alternatively, how about grouping all the 256 files in the lowest leaf into one bigger file? Then you can read multiple numbers in one go, in one cache. And if you used a fixed width file, then you can quickly use seek() to get to any entry in the file in O(1).

Some timings, writing 1000 times on the same file:

- Your original approach: 1.87690401077
- My first approach (open with rw+): 0.0926730632782
- My second approach, copy to the same partition: 0.464048147202

(all functions untested on their error handling path)

Comment: let me try your first approach. I'll get back and comment in a few hours for results. I'll try and reach the bottle neck when the files get too many.

Yes I won't use bare excepts but understand that this is sort of a proof of concept

Comment: The first approach is indeed faster. But after the total file count reaches more than a million, and after the total file size reaches more than 1Gb, performance goes down dramatically even with files properly sized to the FS's block size

Answer (score 0):

If you under linux and got large memory(64GB+), try `tmpfs`, its truly works like mounted disk and you do not need to change your code or buy another SSD.