# Time needed of simulations in loop (c++ app, but also python) increases in time

Tags: python, c++, windows-7-x64

I have a xeon workstation with 16 cores and 32 threads. On that machine I run a large set of simulations in parellel, split on 32 processes that each involve 68,750 (total 2,2 Milion) simulations in a loop.

Data is written on a ssd drive and a python process (while loop with waiting time) gathers the output, consolidates it and stores it away at another regular harddisk, continuously.

Now, at when I start everything and for about the first day, a single simulation only takes a few seconds (all simulations have very similar complexity/load). But then, the time the single simulations take gets longer and longer, up to a hundred-folth after about a week. The cpu temperatures are fine, the disk-tempratures are fine, etc.

However, whereas at the beginning Windows uses all CPU power at 100% is throttles the power a lot when it gets slow (I have a tool running that shows the load of all 32 threads). I tried to hybernate and restart, just to check if it is something with the hardware, but this does not change it, or not very much.

Has anybody any explanation? Is there a tweak to apply to windows to change this behaviour? I can of course do some work around, like splitting the simulations further appart and restarting the machine completely every now and then, starting a new set of simulations again. But I am interested in experience and hopefully solutions to this problem, instead.

**On comments 1,2**: Yes, there are no leaks (tested the c++ code with valgrind) and the usage is stable. The system has 192 GB of Ram available and it only uses a small proportion of it (the 32 simulations each about 190MB), **and** in the c++ everything is closed. For python I guess too (leaving scope there closes handles, if I am not mistaken). However, closing the python programe doesn't change a thing.

Thanks!
Frederik

Comment: Is your memory usage stable ?

Comment: You do release all resources once you're done with them? Not only free memory you allocate, but also close all files and other handles?

Comment: See edit. I think so, yes.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Here are some that come to mind. (1) Does this occur on other OSs? This would prove it is a problem with your code or Windows. (2) How do you start the simulations? What is the scheduling priority shown in the Task Manager? Does it change? Have you tried "start /hi ...." or "start /realtime ..." to set the priority? (3) Have you installed Windows as a server or as a standard desktop installion? Have you used the control panel to configure the desktop installation to be more server-like?

Comment: are simulations *truly* indipendent ? or they use (either directly or indirectly) some common data structure instances ?

Comment: @JustinFinnerty (1) I do not know. (2) there is a c++ compiled (.exe) file which takes as an argument the simulation-configuration to load. I start this via a cmd batch (using start) 32 times, each time using a different configuration file. The scheduling priority is normal. Changing priorities seems to have no (visible) effect on cpu load. (3) Windows 7 Enterprise edition is installed and I have some tweaks (like no automatic restart / updates), but besides this it is still a standard desktop OS.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I guess they are truly independent, as I start each one individually. Although, they are instances of the same executable. They also read the same input file, but only once at the beginning (i.e. in the first simulation of each set). Thereafter everything is storred in the memory throughout. The size in Memory between the simulations is exactly the same in the task-manager, as it should (only computational load can vary, but also only a bit).

Comment: I have a potential answer... As I am saving the data to disk in several files and also create files to mark a simulation as in progress and done (deleting the "in progress" marker) the ssd might cause the problems, because the cache is filled.
And in case of the python script it is even worse. I am reading data from the ssd and writing to a hd, including a "consolidated" marker filed for each run such processed.
I got the idea from: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/3031582/3895476](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3031582/3895476)